# Trying to find height of a canvas using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm a complete beginner doing the odin project working on a task and I've hit a wall and was wondering if anyone could help.

Essentially, I'm trying to make an etch a sketch using jquery and javascript, it can be found here:

http://zackvs.github.io/etchasketch/

source here:

https://github.com/zackvs/etchasketch

After clicking the play buton, the problem i'm having is:

I want to start a path in the middle of the canvas and so as a first step i'm trying to find the height and width of the canvas which i'm testing using:

```
    "console.log($('#draw').width() + " x " + $('#draw').height);"
```

The console displays the width perfectly but for the height returns a v. long string which means absolutely nothing to me (starting with: "(d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d)," etc etc).

Why is this happening?

I'm completely in over my head so any help would be appreciated, I've had a good old google but to no avail.

((Also as a sidenote I spent a lot of time trying to make the site resposive but on resizing the layout slowly comes out of line? I'm sure I've done the whole thing in a silly way with the percentages but how else can i do it?))

Thanks! sorry for long q but it's my first ever here.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
```

This is just the Javascript way to do it. You could try it and see if it works for you.